# Executing Batch File on Remote Server Itself using C#

Tags: c#

I need to execute a batch file on remote server itself . I was using the below code as i found as an example but the batch file is getting executing on the application server itself and not on the remote server. If i need to create a log file using the batch file on remote server , it was throwing error stating file path cannot be found .Thanks for the help in advance

```
 if (File.Exists(filePath))
                {
                    var process = new Process();

                    var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
                    {
                        CreateNoWindow = true,
                        FileName = "cmd.exe",
                        Arguments = "/c \"\"" + filePath + "\"\"",
                        WorkingDirectory = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory,
                        //WorkingDirectory = workingdirectory,
                        UseShellExecute = false,
                        RedirectStandardError = true,
                        RedirectStandardOutput = true
                    };

                    process.StartInfo = startInfo;
                    process.Start(); 
                    //process.WaitForExit(30000);
                    string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
                    string errors = process.StandardError.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Remote process execution is a highly nontrivial thing. `Process.Start()` won't do it. Look into things like `psexec` and PowerShell remoting. With C# only, WMI is probably your best bet.

Comment: Or you could provide some kind of server application (e.g. a common and fairly easy thing to do would be a HTTP server, such as IIS with ASP.NET/C# code) on the remote server to listen to requests from the application server. On receiving a (valid) request the remote server code would execute the batch file, and return the response. Just like a miniature API, really.

Answer (score 0):

The work around for executing the batch file on remote server itself is to do a windows scheduler job and trigger the job by some c# code .Please find the below code to do that

```
 string job = @"""\JobLocation\JobName""";
            string server = @"XXXXXXXXXXX";
            string user = @"Domian\XXXXXX";
            string pwd = @"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
            string line = @" /run /tn " + job + " /s " + server + " /u " + user + "  /p " + pwd;

            var process = new Process();
            var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                CreateNoWindow = true,
                FileName = @"C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\schtasks.exe",
                WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
                Arguments = line,
                //WorkingDirectory = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory,
                UseShellExecute = false,
                RedirectStandardError = true,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true
            };
            process.StartInfo = startInfo;
            process.Start();
            process.WaitForExit();
            string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
            string errors = process.StandardError.ReadLine();code here
```